# Ideals in $Z_{24}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The ideals in $Z_{24}$ are

$(\overline{0}), (\overline{12}), (\overline{8}), (\overline{6}), (\overline{4}), (\overline{3}), (\overline{2})$ and $Z_{24}$ itself.

Now why isn't, say, $(\overline{5})$, also an ideal in $Z_{24}$?

Ie. $(\overline{5})$ contains the elements $\overline{0}, \overline{5}, \overline{10}, \overline{15}, \overline{20},$ and then $\overline{25}$ which is equal to $\overline{1}$ which will generate $Z_{24}$ itself, which is an ideal.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying "also an ideal" would imply $(\bar{5})$ isn't *already listed*.

But as you note, $(\bar{5})=Z_{24}$ and $Z_{24}$ is already in the list.

Answer (score 2):

In an arbitrary ring with unity, if the multiplicative identity $1$ is contained in an ideal $I$, then $I = R$ since $I$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$. That is, if $1 \in R$ then for any $r \in R$, $r = r\cdot 1 \in I$.

In your case, $(\overline 5)$ is an ideal (it's just the ring itself), as you noted, so there's no need to repeat it in your list of ideals.

Answer (score 1):

If an ideal contains an identity element,then it is hole of mother set, as $([5])$ contains $[1]$, then this ideal is equal to $Z_{24}$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z_{24} = \mathbb Z /24\mathbb Z$ and so by the isomorphism theorem the ideals in $\mathbb Z_{24}$ are in bijection with the ideals in $\mathbb Z$ that contain $24\mathbb Z$ and these are exactly those generated by the divisors of $24$.